# Overflow Scroll Not Working IOS

Tags: ios, scroll, overflow

I have a div which I would like to be scrollable, I have added the following code but it doesn't seem to work on iOS devices, works perfectly for Andriod.

I searched and found that adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; should resolve the problem, however it still isn't allowing me to scroll :/

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .fotorama__nav--thumbs {
        height: 180px !important;
    }
    .fotorama__nav--thumbs .fotorama__nav__shaft {
        z-index: 99999;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
    }
    .fotorama__nav__shaft .fotorama__thumb {
        height: 65px !important;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the above isn't working?